# Java Date Time as ISO_DATE_TIME

Tags: java, datetime, localdate

I want to add a Z at the end of DateTimeFormatter ISO_DATE_TIME in Java not hard coded

```
String sample = "2018-05-11T13:35:11Z";

DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[.SSS][XXX][X]");

DateTimeFormatter df1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");

LocalDateTime newLocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(sample, df1);

System.out.println(newLocalDateTime.toString());
```

Output is:

```
2018-05-11T13:35:11
```

I want the output to be `2018-05-11T13:35:11Z`

Comment: You are correct if I understand you correctly: hardcoding the `Z` as a literal in the format pattern string is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `toString()` of your `LocalDateTime`, you should be calling `format`. Change

```
System.out.println(newLocalDateTime.toString());
```

to

```
System.out.println(newLocalDateTime.format(df1));
```

Outputs

```
2018-05-11T13:35:11Z
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the output to have a time zone offset like `Z`, you should use `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("2018-05-11T13:35:11");

OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
System.out.println(odt); // prints: 2018-05-11T13:35:11Z

ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
System.out.println(zdt); // prints: 2018-05-11T13:35:11Z
```

As you can see, the `toString()` method will return the date in the format you requested.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn’t use `LocalDateTime`. Use `OffsetDateTime`. And you may need no formatter.

```
    String sample = "2018-05-11T13:35:11Z";

    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(sample)
            .withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);

    System.out.println(dateTime.toString());
```

Output from this snippet is the dsesired:

> 2018-05-11T13:35:11Z

The call to `withOffsetSameInstant()` makes sure that the date and time are in UTC even if the input had not been. I am using `OffsetDateTime.toString()` to produce the output string. I am exploiting the fact that both your sample string and your desired output are in ISO 8601 format. `OffsetDateTime` and the other classes from java.time parse ISO 8601 format as their default, that is, without any explicit formatter, and produce ISO 8601 format from their `toString` methods.

`OffsetDateTime.toString()` on one hand will leave out the seconds if they are 0, will on the other hand include a fraction of second if it is non-zero (all of this agress with ISO 8601). If you don’t want this, you do need a formatter. For example:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");
    System.out.println(dateTime.format(formatter));
```

You are correct, you should not hardcode `Z` as a literal in the format pattern string. `Z` signifies an offset of zero from UTC. Use format pattern letter `X` to output the offset so you are sure the offset is always correct. This will print an offset of zero as `Z`.

A `LocalDateTime` doesn’t keep a UTC offset, so when parsing into one your are losing information. Don’t do this. Parse into an `OffsetDateTime` to pick up all the information from the string.

**Link:** [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)